# Generating random unique IDs in a pattern in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

In a web app using CouchDB I need to generate unique IDs that consists of Two letters and six digit number, which is used as key in url to access document. IDs will be random,  not sequential. What is the best practice to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [update handlers](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs.html#update-functions) to create/update docs with `_id` value that fits your requirements and [validation functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) to verify that stored document has valid `_id` field.

The implementation of _id generator function should be very easy. [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript) here on StackOverflow for example.